# mac screengrab creates two files

Tags: macos, terminal, screenshot

I ran two commands in Terminal to (a) turn off screengrab shadows, and (b) to change the default save location for screengrabs.

The shadows are now gone and the screengrabs save where I want them to. However, when I invoke command-shift-3 to create a screengrab of the entire desktop, I get *two* files, one containing what I want as well as a screengrab of the 'background', that is the desktop (with any open finder windows).

Could anyone suggest a fix? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! Please disregard this question… I feel embarrassed to admit that it had something to do with … er… my dual monitor setup.